# Will this ductwork for my range hood work?

Tags: ducts, range, hood

I installed a new exterior wall vent and ran 6" round galvanized steel duct work through my ceiling joists to the spot where our new range hood will be.

There was a significant amount of PEX plumbing that I couldn't move anymore, so I put a 90 degree bend and brought down the duct through the cavity.

**Question:** Will there be any issue having the wall behind that vent pipe un-drywalled and exposed like it is?

The range hood will cover that spot, but the duct pipe is closely hugging the wall and wasn't sure if that would pose any major problems.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you worried about heat in the wall cavity?

Comment: No I'm not. There will be drywall everywhere else but that spot

Answer (score 1):

[image]
One way to resolve this is to transition from 6” to 5” duct in ceiling space. Dropping below ceiling with 5” duct will give you another 1/2” clearance from the wall.

The reduced size duct on a short run from blower to ceiling probably has a minor impact on airflow. 6” duct is rated for  up to 600 cfm. If your blower is pushing 400-500  there is no significant impact to airflow.  If it is pushing 600 or more there will be a bit  of extra noise.  If it is well over 600cfm your duct is too small .

Comment: What about using semi-rigid 6" flex duct starting in the ceiling and just bending it slightly to give me that 1/2" clearance as it travels to the 6" opening on my 550CFM range hood.

Comment: @jcw. That is also a good plan. Semirigid can be used on range hoods  though there is some concern about grease build up.  Keep your filters clean